# Downloading an Excel workbook

Tags: excel

I have a website that enables a customer to download a .pdf file.

The code on the download page is

```
\\header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=.\Dox\Pt refs.pdf");
readfile(".\Dox\Pt refs.pdf");
```

I wanted to adapt this so that the customer could download an Excel workbook so
I wrote

```
header("Content-Type:  application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=.\Dox\Heap_jok.xlsm");
readfile(".\Dox\Heap_jok.xlms");
```

This worked in so far as a workbook downloaded itself. BUT I could not open the workbook. Instead I got a message saying that the file could not be opened because the file format or file extension is wrong.

If I just transfer the Excel file by hand to the destination computer all is well - it opens OK and the macros work. But if I load the file to the website and then download it,  then it does not open.

Comment: you have xlms you want xlsm

Comment: Thank you. Can't see for looking !